# How to grep specific value from JSON file?

Tags: json, shell, grep

I have a JSON file and content like below:

```
[  
       {  
          "id":"54545-f919-4b0f-930c-0117d6e6c987",
          "name":"Inventory_Groups",
          "path":"/Groups",
          "subGroups":[  
             {  
                "id":"343534-394b-429a-834e-f8774240d736",
                "name":"UserGroup",
                "path":"/Groups/UserGroup",
                "subGroups":[  

                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Now I want to `grep` value of key `id` from the `subGroups` area. How to achive this, if `id` key not duplicate then it can be achieved by:

```
grep -o '"id": "[^"]*' Group.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

But in my case how can I get the value of `id` as it appears two times?

Comment: Don’t parse JSON with regex (again)!

Comment: We are discouraged from answering questions about parsing structured data (YAML, JSON, etc.) with line-based utilities. Please look into `jq` for shell-based JSON parsing.

Comment: @Biffen jq can't use in my case as its not installed in client machine ,for me its restriction to install any new package in linux machine.

Comment: The immediate issue is that you expect a space after the colon, but that is just one of _many_ issues when attempting to parse JSON with regex. Even if you get around that, and get something that happens to work once, there’s a huge risk it will stop working once the JSON changes slightly.

Comment: @Biffen I am not expecting any space ,i just want to get this value `343534-394b-429a-834e-f8774240d736`

Comment: This is where the SO community fails in my opinion. I know the answer but the question will be heavily downvoted, harming my reputation. @Biffen the main danger is parsing pretty-printed vs compact JSON. It's true the structure and content could change, but that's also true of general CLI output that it's considered acceptable to parse with awk, et al.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Your regex is expecting it, but the JSON doesn’t have it. Ergo no match.

Comment: @vintnes There are other issues, e.g. multiple `id` keys in different objects, like here, or accounting for JSON’s escape syntax.

Comment: @Biffen trivial with awk, watch dis

Comment: Parsing JSON like this with `grep`, `awk` et al. _can_ be done _if and only if_ you are in _absolute_ control of the output in the first place. And if you are, then why use JSON? IMHO this question has no (good) answer.

Comment: @Biffen the answer to `why use JSON` when you can't install a JSON parser is usually because you're using some third-party tool that outputs JSON. It's not uncommon.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi when asking how to parse JSON or XML or any other language using only standard UNIX tools (e.g. grep, sed, awk) it's extremely important to state in your question that you only have access to standard UNIX tools and can't install anything else. That way people can answer you using those standard UNIX tools without getting downvoted and you also won't get a bunch of related comments and downvotes.

Comment: @EdMorton Read the whole comment. ‘*if and only if you are in absolute control of the output*’

Comment: @Biffen I did and it changes nothing. You can be in absolute control of the output while still relying on a third party tool that outputs JSON. Tool X outputs JSON that looks like Y, I need the functionality provided by X and Y is a specific subset of JSON so I can write a tool to parse it even without jq or similar. Again, it's not uncommon.

Comment: Does this server you can't install jq on have perl installed?

Answer (score 1):

A valid question to ask your employer is why you're in a position to use the shell but not to use appropriate linux packages. Compare:

```
awk -F '[":,]+' '$2=="subGroups" {f=1} f && $2=="id" {print $3; exit}' file
```

(Brittle solution, will fail if the structure of your JSON changes)

To:

```
jq '.[].subGroups[].id' file
```

Which can handle compact JSON in addition to numerous other realistic complications.

Comment: Crafty, but ‘brittle’ is an understatement. It will fail even if the structure is the same but the _representation_ changes. Don’t get me wrong, it’s a neat use of `awk`, but the caveat cannot be big enough.

Comment: @Biffen You're right. After a small investment in `jq` (and its poor manpage, imo) I refuse to handle JSON without it. However, the OP's problem is real, and I've previously been in a position where I didn't have the power to obtain the software I wanted, so I sympathize. One could conceivably future-proof a POSIX JSON parser, but that would require detailed knowledge of system requirements and history.

Anyway thanks for participating in the discussion instead of just voting.

Comment: this is what i was exactly thinking. If you are allowed to use you should be allowed to use JQ. If any structure changes in the first tag, then the awk will fail. Though its a nice way to find it through Awk.

Answer (score 0):

Using just standard UNIX tools and assuming your sed can tolerate input without a terminating newline (otherwise we can swap out the `tr` for an `awk` command that keeps the last newline):

```
$ tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/.*"subGroups":[^]}]*"id":"\([^"]*\)\".*/\1\n/'
343534-394b-429a-834e-f8774240d736
```

Alternatively with just a call to any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { rec = (NR>1 ? rec ORS : "") $0 }
    END {
        gsub(/.*"subGroups":[^]}]*"id":"|".*/,"",rec)
        print rec
    }
' file
343534-394b-429a-834e-f8774240d736
```